# Using ng-model with ng-options and Restangular with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tastypie, restangular

I'm having issues with getting items in my select element's option list to be set as selected.  My server backend is Django 1.5 with TastyPie as the API.

**The Template (simplified)**

```
<select
    ng-model='dataService.major_minor.department'
    ng-options='d.name for d in dataService.departments'
    name='department'
    class='select2'
    required>
</select>
```

**The Data Service**

```
majorMinor.factory('dataService', function($rootScope, Restangular) {
    var self = {};

    self.degrees = [];
    self.departments = [];
    self.major_minor = false;
    self.majors_and_minors = [];

    self.fetch_degrees = function() {
        Restangular.all('degree').getList().then(function(results) {
            self.degrees = results;
        });
    };

    self.fetch_departments = function() {
        Restangular.all('department').getList().then(function(results) {
            self.departments = results;
        });
    };

    self.fetch_major_minor = function(majorMinorID) {
        Restangular.one('major-minor', majorMinorID).get().then(function(result) {
            self.major_minor = result;
        });
    };

    self.fetch_major_minor_list = function() {
        Restangular.all('major-minor').getList().then(function(results) {
            self.majors_and_minors = results;
        });
    };

    self.fetch_degrees();
    self.fetch_departments();
    self.fetch_major_minor_list();

    return self;
});
```

**The Controller**

```
majorMinor.controller('EditCtrl',
    function($scope, $routeParams, dataService) {

        $scope.dataService = dataService;
        $scope.dataService.major_minor = false;
        $scope.dataService.fetch_major_minor($routeParams.majorMinorID);
    }
);
```

The issue I'm grappling with is that major_minor.department is a foreign key.  TastyPie is returning a full object, so it's not just the department URI.  The dataService.departments array is an array of all the departments available to this user.  If you were to compare the major_minor.department to dataService.departments[indexOfDepartment], they would be equal.

Any thoughts why ng-model is not correctly selecting an ng-option?  It's possible there is a gap in my understanding of Angular/Restangular as this is only my 2nd project using both.

Comment: did you try to post static object into service and load it by your way?

Comment: @MaximShoustin I haven't yet.  With the data binding that Angular does I'm not sure that it would make a difference.  I can try it out it awhile and report back though.

Comment: Using a static object for the options didn't seem to fix anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jack, I ran into a similar problem and was able to solve it by tweaking the ng-options

```
<select
    ng-model='dataService.major_minor.department.id'
    ng-options='d.id as d.name for d in dataService.departments'
    name='department'
    class='select2'
    required>
</select>
```

I then changed my angular service to change the dataservice.major_minor.department from an object to the ID before I POSTed to my express ReSTful service.  That should give you the foreign key coming across the wire in the payload, rather than the denormalized object.  It's a coffeescript service, so a little different than the factory approach you're taking.

```
   save: (major_minor) ->
      major_minor.department = major_minor.department?._id
      @$http.post("/api/major_minor/", major_minor)
```

The angularjs docs talk about this in the ng-options section here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Hope that helps, especially future searchers that are running into this issue.

Comment: Is this maybe supposed to be `d.id as d.name for d in dataService.departments` (added an "as")?